# button slide left to right

Tags: html, css

I was having doubt that in my code when cursor place in that icon it should hover right but my requirement was Instead of right toggle it should toggle left. For your reference I have uploaded my code

So please help me to do this.

[image: image of icon]

```css
.socialIcons .add-cart-new {
  background-color: yellow;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
min-width: 56px;
max-width: 56px;
  height: 2.28571429em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1.5em; /*it's working only when you write text with icon*/
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new i {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new:hover a {
  max-width: 205px;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new {
  background-color: #EC7F4A;
}
.socialIcons .add-cart-new a
{
  position:relative;
  bottom:4px;
  right:0.3px;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="socialIcons">
            <div class="add-cart-new">
              <a href="" class="add-cart-a">
                <i class="fa-3x fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <span class="text-add-cart">Add to cart</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: [How To Create a Toggle Switch](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

Comment: @FortyTwo Not like that. In my code i don't know how to change

Comment: The idea to send the link was maybe you can think of changing your implementation a little. If you override checkbox style then you have the checked state, for which you can `translateX` you icon to the desired position

Comment: Can u please tell me where i have to add this bcoz i am new to Html and css.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the w3schools example from the comments to your question ([link for reference](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)) to position and move your switch from right to left, it could look like this:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #EC7F4A;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #EC7F4A;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-26px);
  transform: translateX(-26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Maybe you can build on that?

Comment: My requirement was Not as you suggested so can you please check my question one again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but here's what I did:
(Comments are inside the code)

Edit: As I read your comment, I finally understood what you mean. To achieve this, just reverse the elements and the translates.

Also, as an added bonus. I created [this fully customisable button in codepen](https://codepen.io/evochrome/pen/OqLLLL?editors=1100). If you'd like, check it out! (change the scss variable `$text-direction` to reverse the text, in which case it uses `flex-direction: row-reverse` to reverse its elements.)

```css
.socialIcons {
  /* Scale button by changing font-size value */
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new {
  background-color: yellow;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a {
  position: relative;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new input{
  /* HIDE Checkbox */
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a > label {
  /* DISPLAY FLEX and align all items in the center vertically */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* change cursor */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* removed min-width (results in ugly extra width)*/
  max-width: 3em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new:hover a > label, .socialIcons .add-cart-new a > input:checked + label {
  /* Expand if hovered or checked */
  max-width: 12em;
}

/* WHEN UNCHECKED */

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a > input + label > i {
  /* initial margin 0 */
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a > input:not(:checked) + label > span{
  /* initially invisible */
  position: relative;
  max-width: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: 0.5s hideNpop ease-in-out;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a > input + label > span:after{
  /* Text (initially invisible) */
  content: 'Add to cart';
  /* text to caps as in example image */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new:hover a > input + label > i{
  /* Add margin to icon */
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new:hover a > input + label > span{
  /* span visible */
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 12em;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new:hover a > input + label > span:after{
  /* Text (make visible) and add padding to the right */
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new input + label {
  /* Initial background-color */
  background-color: #EC7F4A;
}

/* WHEN CHECKED (same styles when hovering an unchecked except for the color and text)*/

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a > input:checked + label > i {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  /* Move the icon from right to the left */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2.05em) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-2.05em) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-2.05em) rotate(45deg);
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a > input:checked + label > span{
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 12em;
  /* Move the text from left to the right */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(3em);
  -ms-transform: translateX(3em);
  transform: translateX(3em);
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new a > input:checked + label > span:after{
  /* Change text */
  content: 'Added!';
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 6em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  animation: 0.5s hideNpop ease-in-out;
}

.socialIcons .add-cart-new input:checked + label {
  /* Checked background-color */
  background-color: #82ca9c;
}


@keyframes hideNpop {
  /* Real quick fade out and slower fade in*/
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="socialIcons">
  <div class="add-cart-new">
    <a class="add-cart-a">
      <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox" class="text-add-cart">
        <span></span>
        <i class="fa-3x fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
      </label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have any question, feel free to ask! 
Cheers!

Comment: My requirement was not like this. Can you please check the image i have uploaded above. The hover effect need to be remove and  when i click the button or that icon it should move left.